# delete bash hash for particular executable path

Tags: bash, path, command

I have a command called `gmx` at these two paths:

```
/usr/local/bin/gmx
```

and

```
/Users/alexamil/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/bin/gmx
```

how can I delete the bash hash for just one of them?

if I run:

```
hash -d gmx
```

which one is it deleting? Is it deleting both, or just the most recent value? Is this valid to delete a particular one?

```
hash -d  "/Users/alexamil/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/bin/gmx"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bash only remembers one path per name, so it will only have one path for `gmx` (at most). You can see which one that is by running

```
hash -t gmx
```

Running

```
hash -d gmx
```

will delete any entry for `gmx` (the one shown by `hash -t`). The next time you try to run `gmx`, the shell will look for it in directories listed in your `PATH`, and store the first one it finds as the hash.

You can’t delete a particular value, but you can force a particular value, including one not on your `PATH`:

```
hash -p /usr/local/bin/gmx gmx
```

This will cause the shell to run `/usr/local/bin/gmx` when you type `gmx`.

See [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-hash) for details.